# x*x versus table_of_sqr[x] = no difference?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm writing heavy image processing algorithms for iPhone using Xcode4 and official SDK. I need to compute squares a lot of times in my code, always for unsigned char x. So, to make it faster I declared a table:

```
int table[255] = {0, 1, 4, 9,... };
```

and instead of

```
int sqr = x * x;
```

I'm getting values from that table

```
int sqr = table[ABS(x)];
```

Unfortunately, when I'm profiling my app in iPhone simulator, it tells me that this one line (getting value from table) takes more than 50% of app execution time, so it's not a big improvement compared to computing `sqr` at any time. What I'm doing wrong? It should much faster, but I could be wrong, I'm a beginner in this programming environment.

Comment: Replaced all square root stuff with squares.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you're not computing the square root, you're just computing a square, a significantly less-expensive operation. Secondly, if your compiler isn't being clever with caching or constant propagation, a memory look up is usually more expensive than a squaring operation.

Why did you choose to optimize that line originally? Did you profile and decide the old way of doing it wasn't sufficiently efficient/fast?

Comment: Yes, I'm computing squares, like I said before. This was only example of what I'm trying to compute. In my code I have compute a little bit more complicated equation: s = (x/3)*^2 for x between -765 and 765. I have to do it many times, and profiler tells me that this takes a lot of time to execute. So I decided to declare a table with precomputed values for x between 0 and 765.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not faster. Most CPUs have a single cycle operation for multiplying integers, where as an array lookup means an operation that needs to do a much slower memory access.

Comment: Currently my modifications makes execution time of this equation about 5% shorter. But this is not a huge improvement. I read in many books, even on stackoverflow, that preparing a table with precomputed values is good solution for making "SQRT" faster.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode can show Asm.  Look at the assembly language code generated and you will most likely find the abs and indexed array access requires several more ARM instructions than a simple multiply.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not that good to read or even reverse engineer Assembler code. But I've already replaced ABS() instruction with if( (x>>31) == -0x01 ) { ... -1*x ... }  else { ... x ... }